# Laptop Stuck on Boot after Windows Update

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-update, windows-10-v1903

Tech Stack: Windows 10 1909 (OS Build 18363.778);

I noticed lately that if I boot my laptop after a Shutdown on the previous day it just gets stuck on Manufacturer's Boot screen; In my case I have ASUS ZenBook and my device does not go any where else other than being freezed in the Screen where it shows Manufacturer's Logo. To overcome this, I have to forcefully shutdown the device by holding on to the Power button for few seconds and switching back it again. I have noticed on the 2nd try it boots, but I see a loading circle unlike in my first attempt before I was able to see the username and password screen.

This behavior was noticed after the following Windows Update got installed:

- KB4552152
- KB4549951
- KB4537759 (I uninstall this then it worked fine,but after it installed again this started again)
- KB4541338
- KB4537572
- KB4497165

In the Event Viewer I noticed the following:

- Event ID 6008\EventLog: The previous system shutdown at [date and time] was unexpected
- Event ID 41\Kernel Power: The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down  first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed or lost power unexpectedly.
- Event ID 5719\NETLOGON: This computer was not able to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain.
- Event ID 7023\Service Control Manager: The MessagingService_9a182 service terminated with the following error: The device is not ready.
- Event ID 1129\GroupPolicy: The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient condition. A success message would be generated once the machine gets connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has successfully processed. If you do not see a success message for several hours, then contact your administrator.

I have given the device a proper shutdown, but it always give this problem when I switched back.

Thank You,

Comment: Get the machine running, then run CHKDSK without /F to fix errors and see if there are disk errors. If not update BIOS, Chipset and Video drivers.  Restart and test the overall operation.

Comment: There's not much you can do. Some recent KBs have "broken" Windows 10 until a fix was issued, and I believe that's the case with the latest Patch Tuesday batch of updates and fixes.

Comment: Interesting point, but it is machine dependent. My machines here are working fine and the few I had to remote into are working fine as well.

Comment: KB4537759 is a Flash player update, if you don't use IE or Edge, you can skip this update or download it and dry a manual install>>>https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4537759

Comment: UPDATE: This behavior was witnessed among very few of our members. What's more interesting is all of them had the same machine; Same brand and same specs. Since we all work from home, we are yet see any other members have faced the issue.

Comment: UPDATE: I turned off the Fast Startup in the Power Settings and it seems it worked out today, but will review for few days.

Comment: @John I did the CHKDSK and it said there weren't any problems and did not affect the current behavior as well.

Comment: UPDATE: Turning Off Fast Startup did not do good. Only once it solve the problem but the problem is back ever since after that.

Comment: @Didier Is there any resources relating to latest Patch Tuesday? Can you share with us?

Comment: Here's the detail of the latest Patch Tuesday (https://www.ghacks.net/2020/04/14/microsoft-windows-security-updates-april-2020-overview/), with known issues about two third down the page. In your case, if you installed or updated "Modern" apps via GPO, this could be the reason for your trouble. Regardless of you thinking you gave your PC the proper shutdown, Windows thinks otherwise. Can you get it to boot in Safe Mode? If so, go to your System preferences in Control Panel and temporarily disable the pagefile (it's probably corrupted for some reason), and try to restart with no Fast Startup.

Comment: I have updated the device to Windows 10 2004 and even BIOS but still this problem props out, but not often; There is no Consistency of this issue. I have check the `Event ID 7023` and corresponding Service, the `Messaging Service` which always remains stopped. Tried to enable it then got the error `Parameter incorrect`